# How can I cast a memory address to a user defined type in the VS2019 watch window when debugging assembly?

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, x86, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to debug a crash in an exe where my own code is in a dll the exe is loading. I have an assembly only callstack in the exe, and managed to trace back to my own code and find addresses of my own objects that I wish to debug.

However I don't seem to be able to cast the memory addresses to my own types in the watch window: I just get 'identifier "(my type)" is undefined'.

I am guessing this just isn't possible when I'm not in a stack of my own code, but it seems like the debugger *could* know the types if I could give it more information somehow.

I have tried a few of my own types but all give identifier undefined.
I also looked into exported symbols for my types to see if there was something there I could use (based on a suggestion in another SO post), however I think the pdb itself contains the type information I need to point the debugger at.

Of course my pdb is loaded for my own dll, but the watch window seems to not want to look at it when not related stack frames.

Comment: Are you using the fully qualified type, i.e. including namespace?

Comment: How do you cast it? Are you sure that stack is not corrupted?

Comment: @stijn The type does not reside within a namespace, so yes as far as I know it is the fully qualified type.

Comment: @VTT I cast it like (mytype*)0x12345678, stack surely shouldn't matter if I have the address? However pretty sure the stack is fine, the object at the memory location is valid, I can inspect it directly via Memory window and confirm as much. I just want to more easily debug the object using the watch window instead of having to do something like (int*)(0x12345678+4) or whatever to look at the members.

Comment: Make sure that Visual Studio is configured to download symbols from Microsoft's symbol server.  You can do this, IIRC, via Menu ->Options->Debugging.  You should get a better stack trace after you do this.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the stack trace, I already know what I am looking at, I just can't get the watch window to display it as my type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to specify your dll's module name, like `(yourDll.dll!mytype*)0x12345678`

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/context-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for thanks a lot!